# How to filter unique array and add up the duplicates ones in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

**It is coming from a API so i do not have any control**

I have used json_decode($response, true) before getting this result-

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [status] => ok
                [res] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => C_6
                                [image_url] => https://www.example.com/pic.png
                                [cat_id] => F_1
                                [cat_name] => Sea Food
                                [date] => 2020-11-09 22:02:56
                            )
    
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => C_6
                                [image_url] => https://www.example.com/pic1.png
                                [cat_id] => F_1
                                [cat_name] => Sea Food
                                [date] => 2020-11-09 12:12:20
                            )
    
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => C_6
                                [image_url] => https://www.example.com/pic2.png
                                [cat_id] => F_2
                                [cat_name] => European Dish
                                [date] => 2020-11-09 20:05:62
                            )
             )
    
                [none] => 
            )
    
    )
```

Now I want to filter result based on unique on the basis of this element **[date]** and only the date I want that all the results should be unique and duplicate values should add up to like this -

There is 2 "*Sea Food*" with same date but with different timestamp (that I have figured out to explode and take out the date only from it)

But I want only to consider it duplicate if the dates are same for the same category (just like Sea Food)
If in anycase there are 3 arrays with 2 same date and 1 different date but same category then it will be 2~1st date and 1~2nd date

Sea Food-2020-11-09 **+** Sea Food-2020-11-09 = 2 Sea Food on 2020-11-09

**So in total it is:-**
2 Sea Food, 1 European dish

Comment: where do you get this result from, is it database records cause you may consider updating your query to do this job for you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the optimised solution, but if I understand your needed, please try this :

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 'C_6',
        'cat_id' => 'F_1',
        'cat_name' => 'Seafood',
        'date' => '2020-11-09 22:02:56',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'C_7',
        'cat_id' => 'F_1',
        'cat_name' => 'Seafood',
        'date' => '2020-11-09 22:02:50',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'C_9',
        'cat_id' => 'F_8',
        'cat_name' => 'Tacos',
        'date' => '2020-11-09 22:02:50',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'C_6',
        'cat_id' => 'F_6',
        'cat_name' => 'Europe',
        'date' => '2020-12-09 20:05:56',
    ],
];
$days = [];
$result = [];
//loop over all your data
foreach($data as $item) {
    //keep only your date
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['date']);
    $category = $item['cat_id'];
    $cat_name = $item['cat_name'];
    $day = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    //better to use the category id instead of a string, IMO
    //but depends on your data structure
//    $days[$day][$category][] = $item;
    $days[$day][$cat_name][] = $item;
}

foreach($days as $date => $item) {
    foreach($item as $cat_name => $value) {
        $result[] = count($value) . " $cat_name on " . $day;
    }
}
```

The result :

[image]